# How to convert string 21/01/2019 (dd/MM/yyyy) to Date object in same format using Java

Tags: java, string, date, datetime

My input string is "22/12/2019" in "dd/MM/yyyy" format. I need to convert this string into Date object while retaining the format. The output still needs to be in dd/MM/yyyy format but it should be a Date object. Please advise

Comment: Date objects do not have format.

Comment: Check [DateFormat.parse(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

Comment: `Date` is a class. If you want to preserve the format when you convert the date object back to string, then you should use a formatter. In you case, it doesn't make sense. although it can help assign right values to the object.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *Please advise* I advise you not to care about the format of your `LocalDate` object (that you should use instead of `Date`). Only in your interface worry about formats. And only there format your `LocalDate` into a string in the required format.

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("<YOUR FORMAT HERE>");
String dateInString = "15-10-2015 10:20:56";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```

> Please find the formatting samples [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/java-date-examples/)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.